# Latex: Add figure with references

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I have created the figure below in PowerPoint and included it as a picture in Latex. However, now I want to cite some references in the text of the figure. This isn't possible in PowerPoint. So I am looking for an alternative. Do you know a solution to solve this problem? The figure shall go over a column of a two-column document.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason to use PowerPoint in the first place? If not, you could use TikZ to produce an image like yours. In this image you can use references and the text will be printed in the same font as the text of your main document (which is not the case when using PowerPoint).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{biblatex}
    
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@article{Einstein,
author   = {Einstein},
title    = {Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
    
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=black, fill=white, text width=0.9\textwidth] at (0,0) {Here you use references like \cite{Einstein}.};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This MWE is not the best, but I hope that it shows that TikZ could be an option.

Comment: Hey, yes, that looks very promising. I already have tried if \itemize is possible and it is. Thank you. I will write again if more questions arise.

Comment: Ok,  I have tied to add \usepackage{tikz} in my document. However, then 2 errors occur: "! Missing number, treated as zero." and "! Extra \fi."

Comment: Found a solution: https://shantoroy.com/latex/tikz-package-compatibility-in-ieee-access-latex-template/ Thank you very much!!!

Comment: The package is working now. However, I have problems to create the figure from above. How can I insert the text boxes as above? I have tried it with "at (0.2)". However, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: The solution would be to use a command as: "place the second box 3mm below the end of the first box". Someone knows a solution for this?